# how to configure jest unit test framework in SharePoint SPFx + react project

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, sharepoint, jestjs, spfx

I have tried to configure jest unit test framework in react with SharePoint SPFx projects

Below I mention all code related to jest configurations and test cases as well as

Project is configured in react + gulp for SharePoint SPFx

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "pnp-sp-crud",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.10.0",
    "@pnp/common": "^2.0.3",
    "@pnp/sp": "^2.0.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/react": "16.8.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "jest-cli": "^27.3.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "6.189.2",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-block-ui": "^1.3.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "16.8.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.3": "0.3.5",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules": "1.10.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "1.10.0",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.7",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  }
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest",
    },
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
        "/node_modules/"
    ],
    testRegex: [
        '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.[jt]sx?$'
    ]
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.3/includes/tsconfig-web.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "inlineSources": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/@microsoft"
    ],
    "types": [
      "es6-promise",
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom",
      "es2015.collection"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "lib"
  ]
}
```

**PnpSpCrud.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './PnpSpCrud.module.scss';
import { IPnpSpCrudProps } from './IPnpSpCrudProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
require("@pnp/logging");
require("@pnp/common");
require("@pnp/odata");
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";
import BlockUi from 'react-block-ui';

export default class PnpSpCrud extends React.Component<IPnpSpCrudProps, {
  name: any,
  tech: any,
  employees: any[],
  isUpdate: boolean,
  empId: any,
  empIndex: any,
  blocking: boolean
}> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      tech: '',
      employees: [],
      isUpdate: false,
      empId: '',
      empIndex: '',
      blocking: false
    };

    this.getEmployee();
    this.enterName = this.enterName.bind(this);
    this.enterTechnology = this.enterTechnology.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  private enterName(event) {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  }

  private enterTechnology(event) {
    this.setState({ tech: event.target.value });
  }

  private handleSubmit(event) {
    this.addEmployee(this.state);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IPnpSpCrudProps> {
    return (
      <BlockUi tag="div" blocking={this.state.blocking}>
        <div className={styles.pnpSpCrud}>
          <div className={styles.container}>
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <div className={styles.column}>
                {/* <span className={styles.title}>Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
              <p className={styles.subTitle}>Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
              <p className={styles.description}>{escape(this.props.description)}</p> */}
                <h4>Add Employee</h4>
                <form>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Employee Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.enterName} />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Technology</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Technology" value={this.state.tech} onChange={this.enterTechnology} />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* <input type="text" placeholder="Employee Name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.enterName}></input>
                  <input type="text" style={{ marginLeft: 5 }} placeholder="Technology" value={this.state.tech} onChange={this.enterTechnology}></input>
                  <div style={{ marginTop: 5 }}>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                  </div> */}
                  </div>
                </form>
                <button className="btn btn-primary mb-5" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
                <h4>Employees</h4>
                <table className="table table-dark">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th>#</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th colSpan={2}>Technology</th>
                    </tr>
                    {
                      this.state.employees.map((ele, index) => {
                        return (
                          <tr>
                            <td>{index + 1}</td>
                            <td>{ele.Title}</td>
                            <td>{ele.tech}</td>
                            <td style={{ color: 'while', cursor: 'pointer' }}><i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" onClick={() => this.updateEmployee(ele.ID, index)}></i></td>
                            <td style={{ color: 'while', cursor: 'pointer' }}><i className="fa fa-trash" style={{ color: 'while' }} aria-hidden="true" onClick={() => this.deleteEmployee(ele.ID, index)}></i></td>
                          </tr>
                        );
                      })
                    }
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                {/* <a href="https://aka.ms/spfx" className={styles.button}>
                <span className={styles.label}>Learn more</span>
              </a> */}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BlockUi>
    );
  }

  private getEmployee() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sp.web.lists.getByTitle('EmployeeList').items.select('ID, Title, tech').get().then((result: any[]) => {
        console.log("get employees result", result);
        resolve(result);
        this.setState({
          employees: result
        });
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("error in get employees", err);
      });
    });
  }

  private addEmployee(state) {
    if (this.state.name && this.state.tech) {
      if (this.state.isUpdate) {
        this.setState({ blocking: true });
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let data = {
            Title: state.name,
            tech: state.tech
          };
          sp.web.lists.getByTitle('EmployeeList').items.getById(this.state.empId).update(data).then((result: any) => {
            resolve(result);
            alert('Employee Updated');
            this.state.employees[this.state.empIndex].Title = data.Title;
            this.state.employees[this.state.empIndex].tech = data.tech;
            this.setState({ name: '', tech: '', isUpdate: false, empId: '', empIndex: '', blocking: false });
          }).catch((err) => {
            alert('Employee Not Updated');
            this.setState({ blocking: false });
            console.log("error in update employee", err);
          });
        });
      }
      else {
        this.setState({ blocking: true });
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let data = {
            Title: state.name,
            tech: state.tech
          };
          sp.web.lists.getByTitle('EmployeeList').items.add(data).then((result: any) => {
            console.log("result from add employee", result);
            resolve(result);
            alert('Employee added');
            this.state.employees.push({
              ID: result.data.ID,
              Title: state.name,
              tech: state.tech
            });
            this.setState({ name: '', tech: '', blocking: false });
          }).catch((err) => {
            alert('Employee not added');
            this.setState({ blocking: false });
            console.log("error in add employee", err);
          });
        });
      }
    }
    else {
      alert("Enter Name and Technology");
    }
  }

  private updateEmployee(id, index) {
    this.setState({ blocking: true });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sp.web.lists.getByTitle('EmployeeList').items.getById(id).get().then((result: any) => {
        console.log("get employee by id result", result);
        resolve(result);
        this.setState({
          name: result.Title,
          tech: result.tech,
          isUpdate: true,
          empId: id,
          empIndex: index,
          blocking: false
        });
      }).catch((err) => {
        this.setState({ blocking: false });
        console.log("error in get employee by id", err);
      });
    });
  }

  private deleteEmployee(id, index) {
    this.setState({ blocking: true });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sp.web.lists.getByTitle('EmployeeList').items.getById(id).delete().then((result: any) => {
        console.log("delete employee by id result", result);
        resolve(result);
        alert("Employee deleted");
        this.state.employees.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({
          empId: '',
          empIndex: '',
          blocking: false
        });
      }).catch((err) => {
        this.setState({ blocking: false });
        console.log("error in delete employee by id", err);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

**PnpSpCrud.spec.tsx**

```
import PnpSpCrud from '../PnpSpCrud';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
    expect(PnpSpCrud).toBeTruthy();
});
```

[Error while run the unit test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/208mi.png)

Answer (score 0):

jest (or any other unit testing framework) is not currently officially supported for SPFx, as far as I know.

I faced the similar issues, please check out this thread on GitHub discussing how to make jest work with SPFx and PNP:
https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/1425

This is the demo repo with working config:
https://github.com/nbelyh/spfx-unit-testing-pnpjs

Comment: Thanks, @nikolay for the response.
I have found one more solution you also can try to configure jest in the SPFx project: https://github.com/Voitanos/jest-preset-spfx-react16

Comment: It is mentioned in the post above, please check out these comments related to issues with it: https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/1425#issuecomment-721110960

Comment: Got it.
Can you please also take look at another same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69973511/sharepoint-framework-spfx-using-pnp-sp-presets-all-with-react-sharepoint-spfx

Comment: Please read the comment with the link above, it seems to address the issue you are facing.

Comment: I have sawn your GitHub issue. But don't have any solutions on **Import PNP**.
I also check out your repo: spfx-unit-testing-pnpjs. But in my case, I need to use import for SharePoint List and SPFx component.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm I think the solution has demo for testing both service (that is using PNP) and the component? BTW, feel free to create an issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

First to explain why You suffer this issue - jest uses commonjs modules and spfx  related libraries and pnp libraries doesn't have commonjs version (usually only es5).
If You wonder why jest is using commonjs - I guess two reasons: it's running in node process and it's easier to mock the whole modules at runtime. This is what I would suggest - mock the pnp library at test runtime. You won't be able to communicate with SharePoint during tests so You would have to mock pnp either way.
I did publish an article on how to start with unit testing SPFx on
[PnP Blog](https://pnp.github.io/blog/post/getting-started-with-unit-testing-spfx)
In it You will find how to handle that case for sp-core-library - use same steps for pnp and Your tests should run.

Also for sure You will need to mock scss modules. You can do it by adding this
to Your jest config:

```
"moduleNameMapper":{
      "\\.(css|scss)": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
```

and installing identity-obj-proxy.

`npm i -D identity-obj-proxy`

If You need more help with this let me know.

I actually created a sample based on Your code with working unit test.
You can find the repo [here](https://github.com/mgwojciech/unit-test-samples/tree/main/spfx-pnp)
Will most likely create a blog post about the details soon.